# Wifi has been really slow on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking

I've tried a lot of solutions already, but none have really worked. The solution mentioned here (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2175345) brought the speed up from 0.5 mb/s to 10 mb/s. However, on Windows 10, the speed is around 50 mb/s, much better.

Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01) is my Network controller.

I don't know what other stats are necessary to help.

I just want my speed to match that of Windows.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Download [this script](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/522934) and [edit](***) your question to include a link to the pastebin output. This way people can have an overview.